# attribute invisible is not working at odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I don't understand, why the invisible attribute of the button can't work at related field. But when the invisible attribute based on another field type condition, likes boolean, that's worked.

My code on my module or my python file is

```
'location_id'       : fields.many2one('stock.location', string='Storage'),
'measurement_type'  : fields.related('location_id','measurement_id', type="many2one", 
                      relation="flow.measure.type", string = "Measurement Type", readonly=True, store=True),
```

and this is my script on the xml file

```
<field name="measurement_type" />
<field name="location_id" required="1" context="{'full':1}"
             on_change="onchange_location(location_id,measure_date)"
            domain="[('usage','not in',['view','transit','inventory']), 
            ('location_id','child_of',parent.location_id)]" />
<button name="open_flowmeter" string="Flowmeter Measurement"
            type="object" icon="fa-exchange" 
            attrs="{'invisible':[('measurement_type','!=',2)]}"/>
```

And the data type for the measurement_type field in the database is integer.

My goal is when the record (measurement_type) is 2, the button appears. But, what happens is the button doesn't appear. And the button still not appears regardless of the record value obtained

> PS. Sorry for my bad grammar

Comment: Did you upgrade the module? what you want is when ever you select a record with id != 2  the button disappears?

Comment: Yes I did. Yes of course. When the record isn't 2, then the button disappears. But the invisible attribute on the button is not working properly

Comment: the button still there even when you select other records?

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean, when the record is 2, the button appears. but what happens is the button doesn't appear

Comment: what if you inverse the domain does the button appear, and are you sure the record Id is 2?

Comment: Are you sure you're working with Odoo 9 and up? Because your field definition is the old API, which you shouldn't use in Odoo 9 and up anymore.

Comment: I'm working with Odoo 9. And yes, I'm using old API

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to use current ORM API. The old API way of declaring columns and related fields should not be used any more. Your code shows only snippets and does not expose exactly what your custom models are, so we are not able to know how you should define your related field. After conversion it should look something like this:

```
location_id = fields.Many2one('stock.location', string='Storage')
measurement_type = fields.Integer(related='location_id.measurement_id.type', string = "Measurement Type", readonly=True, store=True)
```

If necessary fix the `related` parameter for measurement_type field ('location_id.measurement_id.type') to reflect your model structure to get the type value.

You can find the Odoo v9 ORM API developer guide here:https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#related-fields. You can find github issue regarding the new api not supporting the old api way of defining related fields: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/3270